# Split string is not working in MVC controller

Tags: c#, visual-studio, split

I have the following code in my MVC controller:

```
string[] w_result;
string[] w_result2;

string[] new_line = { Environment.NewLine };
string all_copybook = c.original_copybook;

w_result = all_copybook.Split(new_line, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
w_result2 = "abaUUUnns s s".Split('a');
```

When I run it in Visual Studio 2012 through the debugger I see no exception, but when I try to view the value of `w_result` or `w_result2`, I am getting:

> w_result  The name 'w_result' does not exist in the current context
>   w_result2 The name 'w_result2' does not exist in the current context

Any idea why?

Comment: Are you at a breakpoint?

Comment: The the code you posted is contained in the same function, then you should never see that error message. Please provide more context.

Comment: This is exactly my code. I stopped at breakpoint and saw these messages. I added "foreach (string a in w_result)
                {i = 1;}" and strange thing happened - using debugger I saw the cursor moves between "a" and "w_result" - and never hits "i = 1" statement.

Comment: I reboot my machine and more strange thing happened, here is a picture: http://sciepa.org/MVC.png   I defined variables test1 and test2 and they are not recognized, but they are null. No idea what happens.

Comment: Now even more strange: http://sciepa.org/mvc2.png               public ActionResult GetCopyBook()
{
    string test3;
    test3 = "A";
    return View();
} 
the message: "The name 'test3' does not exist in the current context 
How come???

Comment: @ZalekBloom - you must have some optimization set -- those variables are not being used so they are not in the final executable.

Comment: @Hogan - THANK YOU, THANK YOU, THANK YOU, THANK YOU, THANK YOU, THANK YOU - I don't now how it it happen but I changed option to Release instead of debug. Thank you again! zb

Answer (score 1):

For debugging, change your build configuration to Debug instead of Release. The Release configuration can optimize your code and prevent the debugger from seeing some local variables.