# The name 'test1' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, string, visual-studio

In MVC controller I defined a string variable, but still I am getting message: "The name 'test1' does not exist in the current context".

Here is my code:

```
public ActionResult About()
{
  string test1;
  test1 = "A";
  return View();
}
```

I tried to put a breakpoint on all 3 statements, but it stopped only on the "return" command. Here is a picture from Visual Studio 2012 a breakpoint:

[image: Visual Studio Breakpoint]

Any ideas?

Comment: Isn't this essentially the same issue you had here - http://stackoverflow.com/q/17385081/745969?  I notice that in the screenshot above you're still in release mode, even though it was suggested in your other question that you run in debug mode for debugging.

Answer (score 6):

For debugging, change your build configuration to Debug instead of Release. The Release configuration can optimize your code and prevent the debugger from seeing some local variables.

Answer (score 3):

You never use the variable after assigning a value to it, so the compiler is smart enough to know it's meaningless and it can discard it.

Here's what the compiler sees:

```
public ActionResult About()
{
  string test1;   // Declare a variable
  test1 = "A";    // Do something meaningless with it
  return View();  // Don't use it, so throw away the two previous statements
}
```

The compiler is smart enough to know that code that doesn't actually do anything can just be ignored. It's basic optimization - don't compile code that does nothing.

Comment: System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(variableName); can help in this case, where you want to check something you don't actually use yet. It can force the optimiser to keep the variable longer, and it writes the value to your Output window (so you can see it there, if all else fails)

Answer (score 0):

`test1` was likely optimized out because you do not use it in the scope in which it's declared.