# Why can't I see a specific variable in the debugger?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have this C# code in Visual Studio 2013.    It uses a third-party library but I don't know if that's a factor in this problem.    The code builds and executes perfectly.      But there's a variable in it that I can't examine in the debugger.  Here's the entire routine . . .

```
private void AddGeometry()
{
    var simplePositions = CreateRectShape(startPosition: new Point3D(0, 0, 0));
    var simplePositionCollection = new Point3DCollection(simplePositions);
    int size = simplePositionCollection.Count;
    MainViewport.BeginInit();
    MainViewport.Children.Clear();
    var polyLineVisual3D = new Ab3d.Visuals.PolyLineVisual3D()
    {
        Positions = simplePositionCollection,
        LineColor = Colors.DarkOrange,
        LineThickness = 2,
        Transform = new TranslateTransform3D(0, 0, 0)
    };

    MainViewport.Children.Add(polyLineVisual3D);
    MainViewport.EndInit();
}
```

If I breakpoint at the Children.Add() statement and try to examine **polyLineVisual3D** or place a quickwatch on it, I get...

> The name 'polyLineVisual3D' does not exist in the current context

... from Visual Studio.   I have no trouble examining other local variables like simplePositions or simplePositionCollection at the same breakpoint.

Comment: The variable has probably been optimized away by the compiler. Previous discussions [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17386591/the-name-test1-does-not-exist-in-the-current-context) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13517521/variable-does-not-exist-in-the-current-context-while-debugging).

Comment: The build configuration is Active (Debug).  I thought optimization only applied to Release configurations.  Is that wrong?

Comment: If the settings are different from the default ones, then optimization might still be enabled.

Comment: in Build>General, Optimize code is UN-checked.

Comment: A couple more things to try. (1) The debugger might not "see" `polyLineVisual3D` until after it's used. Move the breakpoint to `MainViewport.EndInit();` and see if the error goes away. Alternatively, put `Debug.WriteLine(polyLineVisual3D);` before the `Children.Add(..)` call. (2) Open the options dialog and turn on Debugging/General/Use Managed Compatibility Mode.  There's a Microsoft Connect issue about this bug [here](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1038150/visual-studio-2015-debugger-doesnt-recognize-a-variable).

Comment: You might have to instrument, add a line `System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(polyLineVisual3D.###)` just any property, then you should be able to view the object in the debugger (doing this in hopes to keep the variable from being optimized away).

Comment: @Chris R. Timmons I tried both (1) and (2) and no luck.   But those were good ideas - thanks for suggesting them!   I'm wondering if this has anything to do with the 3rd-party library.    What if the DLL that gets invoked when I access Ab3d.Visuals.PolyLineVisual3D was built with optimizations turned on - could that cause this?

Comment: I installed the trial for the AB4D library.  There's code at the beginning of `TubePathSample.xaml.cs` that's very similar to yours.  I ran the sample app and stepped through the code in that file, but couldn't reproduce the weird behavior you're running into - the debugger inspected `polyLineVisual3D ` without complaint..  For what it's worth, I'm running VS 2013 Update 5 on a Windows 8.1 box.